# Smarty cache not working?

Tags: php, caching, smarty

I am using Smarty in my projects when I enable caching it doesn't seem to work.
I am using the following structure:

> index.php — display(index.tpl)
>
> index.tpl —- {include
>   file=$page_center}
>
> ?module=product —
>   $smarty->assign(”page_center” ,
>   “product.tpl”) ;

In product.php the template product.tpl must loaded in center of index.tpl.
When I enable caching it still shows the default content not product.tpl. When caching is disabled it works fine. What is the problem when caching is enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use a unique cache ID for each page to make this work correctly:

```
$cacheID = 'some_unique_value_for_this_page';
$smarty->assign('page_center', 'product.tpl');
$smarty->display('index.tpl', $cacheID);
```

Given the example you gave in the question, it could make sense to use the module name from your query string as the basis for the cache ID.

There's more information about in the Smarty manual: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.display.php

Comment: ok . i test it but it's dosen't help me unfortunately beacause every time a module calls a new cach file is created in cach directory , it's same as i use $smarty->force_compile . this is way is not correct way to catching i think .

Comment: Old topic now, but having using a value that is unique to that page would do the job for you, so for example, if your product has a product ID number, then use that as your unique cacheID value; Smarty will compile and cache the template for that particular product page once, then refer to the cached version any time it's referred to in the future.

Comment: My solution to language based caching ($cache_id = $lng_id). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need create an dynamic module!

```
function smarty_block_dynamic($param, $content, &$smarty) {
    return $content;
}
```

then

```
$smarty = new Smarty
$smarty->register_block('dynamic',
                        'smarty_block_dynamic',
                        false /* this block wont be cached */);
```

and your tpl

```
Hello {$name}

this is your las update

{/dyamic}
{include file="some/dynamic/thing.tpl"}
{/dynamic}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to solve smarty caching problem, ie if caching is not happening, please check if your templates_c folder has read and write permissions to all